# Vim: bold highlighting only after reload solarized color scheme

Tags: vim, color-scheme, vim-plugin

I have the following minimal `.vimrc` file under `$HOME` directory (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, using `vim-gnome`):

```
syntax on
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

And everything was highlighted as expected except for those supposed to be bold.

By default, solarized color scheme should bold `error`s and `todo`s. However it doesn't work right away. For example, opening a file and invoking `:he group-name`, I get the following:

[image]

You can see `error` and `todo` are not bold. If I now *reload* solarized by `:colo solarized`, the highlighting will finally get correct:

[image]

So what goes wrong here? how can I get solarized to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an workaround:

Put `colo solarized` in `/usr/share/vim/gvimrc` solved the problem.

Initially, I thought some script loaded between `solarized.vim` and `gvimrc` might have conflicted with the bold setting of `solarized.vim`. But It seems not the case, because I've tried putting `colo solarized` in every script between them (based on output of `:script`), which has no effect.

Strangely, It only works fine to put `colo solarized` in `/usr/share/vim/gvimrc`.