# Vim: How to load a script after /usr/share/vim/gvimrc

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

As I asked (and answered myself) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913996/vim-bold-highlighting-only-after-reload-solarized-color-scheme), some vim script is preventing the color scheme `solarized.vim` to load correctly. And I have found a workaround which is to load `solarized.vim` *in* or *after* `/usr/share/vim/gvimrc`.

However, even as a workaround it's not optimal, because I hope all my customization would reside in my `~/.vim` directory (or at least my `$HOME` directory).

So here is my question:

- How to load a script after `/usr/share/vim/gvimrc`?

Especially, If I can create a script `solarized.vim`, putting a single line `colo solarized` in it, and let it loaded after `gvimrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and easy way: create a ~/.gvimrc and put your commands in there.

If you want to keep everything in ~/.vim, however, you could try the suggestion from http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#gvimrc and something like this to your ~/.vim/vimrc file:

```
If you want some commands to be executed just after opening the
GUI window, use the |GUIEnter| autocommand event.  Example:
    :autocmd GUIEnter * colo solarized
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Both the approaches work fine. And I'll take the second one. Thanks also for providing detailed help doc.